# How to change location of Windows desktop folder in C# (.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core

This can be done manually in windows by right clicking the current desktop folder, clicking on  properties and selecting the location tab from the context menu.

I am guessing the path to the desktop needs to be stored somewhere, however I have no idea where to start looking.

CONTEXT:
I am making a tool that would allow me to have different icons and files on each virtual desktop. I have already tried moving all files in the folder instead of the folder itself but that unfortunately doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: Have you tried [Microsoft Desktops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops)?

Comment: This article has tips on how to make a multi-desktop utility using Win32's functions specifically for this purpose: https://scorpiosoftware.net/2019/02/17/windows-10-desktops-vs-sysinternals-desktops/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your desktop folder through the Registry, it's located under:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` The key name is: `Desktop`

I hope this answers your question.

EDIT:
In C# you can use https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHSetKnownFolderPath to change Desktop folder and then reload with F5 or with a script.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for my cause, because the desktop change isn't taken immediately but rather after restarting explorer.exe (or windows)

Comment: According to this answered [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1459395/refresh-desktop-after-registry-edit-without-restarting-explorer-exe) you can use SHSetKnownFolderPath API to change desktop folder and then simply reload via F5.